# How to check for text in ul tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a certain functionality on a website, and I need to check for anything written in-between `<ul></ul>` tags. And when there isn't any, text should be appended between the tags

So far I've tried doing conditional statements but it seems the statements are just being overlooked when I debugged them.

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
if($('ul.list-group').length > 0 === false) {
   $('ul.list-group').append('Drag a page inside or below the box to create a child page');
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `.text()`. `$('ul.list-group').length` ==> `$('ul.list-group').text().length`. I'll also suggest to use `$.trim` on text, before getting `length` of text.

Comment: Note that you can't append text directly to a `ul` element - it needs to be placed within a `li`.

Comment: `length` is returning the number of elements in the jQuery object.not checking for text length

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i see, what should i use to have the same affect as I really need to place the text inbetween the ul tags

Comment: `if($('ul.list-group').length > 0 === false)` so You mean `if($('ul.list-group').length === 0)`?? And why are you appending a text node to a UL?

Comment: I also think that you don't have to append just raw text into the unordered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to collect the text content of the target element and check its length,

```
var elem = $('ul.list-group');
if(!elem.text().length) {
   elem.text('Drag a page inside or below the box to create a child page');
}
```

As *epascarello* pointed out, An UL cannot have a text node as its immediate child. Not exactly, It can. But it is considered as an invalid html. The better approach would be,

```
var elem = $('ul.list-group');
if(!$("li", elem).length) {
   elem.html('<li>Drag a page inside or below the box to create a child page</li>');
}
```

Comment: right this works, however I only want the text to be appended when there isn't anything in the ul tags present

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That is absolutely correct. But we cannot tell exactly that user's dom is having more than one element with this class. Anyway I will add it as a side note.

Comment: So you are setting a UL's text? That is interesting.

Comment: @epascarello Yes. as per OP's markup. It will become an invalid html as UL cannot have a text node as its immediate child. I could have suggested him appending a li element with warning text. But I am not sure whether that will break his other logic(drag/drop) or not.

Answer (score 0):

To find all `ul.list-group` elements that are empty - they don't have child elements or text:

```
$('ul.list-group:empty').text('Drag a page inside or below the box to create a child page');
```

https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

Comment: So you are appending a text node to a UL?

Comment: oh, yes. Forgot about it. Thanks

Comment: So a UL has text? interesting... :)

Comment: @epascarello, that's what the question author stated "text should be appended between the tags". I also think that he doesn't have to append just raw text into the unordered list. But that's what he wanted, I supppose